# "The receipt could not be authenticated" - should it be checked again?

Tags: ios

Out of Apple's status codes for an in-app purchase (in [Table 2-1 here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)), some should obviously be tried again, and some not and should be considered to say that the receipt in invalid.

But what about "21003 - The receipt could not be authenticated."? Is it similar to 21010 or to 21005? I.e. should this be sent again later or considered an invalid purchase?

Answer (score 16):

From my experience, the `"21003 - The receipt could not be authenticated."` status is related to the App-Specific Shared Secret.

When you validate receipts with the AppStore, the App-Specific Shared Secret is used to set the value of the `password` field in the JSON request that you sent to the AppStore validation endpoint. (See [Validating Receipts with the App Store documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store?language=objc))

Keep in mind that according to Apple's documentation, this apps-specific shared secret is only necessary when validating receipt for apps that use auto-renewable subscriptions. However, in my experience, it might be worth setting it for any app receipt validation, just to avoid the 21003 error.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if the shared secret created is brand new, you may need to wait a few hours for it to work properly. I did not find anything in the documentation about this, but I have experienced it many times.