# Sandbox environment returns 21003 status code for receipt validation

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase-receipt

When I test an in-app purchase with the sandbox the post request to the sandbox url https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt returns

```
 data: { environment: 'Sandbox', status: 21003 }
```

The 21003 status code means that the receipt could not be authenticated. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/status?language=objc

Is this expected? I'd assumed my test receipt would be considered valid for the sandbox environment and return a status of 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The receipt could not be authenticated" - should it be checked again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58615404/the-receipt-could-not-be-authenticated-should-it-be-checked-again)

Comment: We’ve been receiving the same error with sandbox receipts from App Review for our macOS app for the last week. When verifying the receipts without a password they return a valid receipt JSON, so the receipt data seems to be ok. The issue in this case seems to be on Apple’s side and we’ve opened a DTS incident to try to get this resolved.

Comment: It returned 21003 for me for about an hour after the shared secret was created. Then it disappeared. I assume it takes some time for the shared secret to take effect after it's created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No its not expected. I needed to provide a valid code in the password field even though the in-app purchase was not for an auto-renewable subscription.

Answer (score 5):

You report that when you send the `appStoreReceipt` to the `verifyReceipt` endpoint that you are seeing the status result 21003. This status indicates that the `appStoreReceipt` was malformed, incomplete, or incorrectly encoded. Can you capture the base64 encoded `appStoreReceipt` and send me the contents as a text file for me to manually validate the contents. If you app process sells an auto-renewing subscription item, please include the app's shared secret. I use the following curl command line tool to validate `appStoreReceipts`.

For sandbox receipts:

```
curl -d '{ "exclude-old-transactions": true "password":"yyyy" "receipt-data": "xxxx"}' https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
```

For production receipts:

```
curl -d '{ "exclude-old-transactions": true "password":"yyyy" "receipt-data": "xxxx"}' https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
```

Where `exclude-old-transactions` is used to limit the contents of the `latest_receipt_info` to only the most recent entry and

"password" is the request key to indicate the shared-secret that is required when the content is an auto-renewing subscription.

yyyy - is the shared-secret and
xxxx - is the base64 encoded content of the `appStoreReceipt`.

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced this error, in my case the shared secret that I was using was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone need a bash script I have wrote for this.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

green='\033[0;32m'
cyan='\033[0;36m'
noColor='\033[0m' # No Color

sig=$1
mode=$2

if [ -z "$mode" ];
  then
    PS3="Please select a mode: "
    options=("Sandbox" "Production")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            "Sandbox") break;;
            "Production") break;;
            *) echo -e ${red}"\ninvalid option" \"$REPLY\"${noColor};;
          esac
        done
    else
      opt=$mode
fi

if [[ "$opt" == "Production" ]]
then
  echo -e ${green}"Production selected"${noColor}
  commandToExecute="curl -d '{\"receipt-data\":\"$sig\"}' https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
else
  echo -e ${cyan}"Sandbox selected"${noColor}
  commandToExecute="curl -d '{\"receipt-data\":\"$sig\"}' https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
fi

eval $commandToExecute
```

Call it like ./scriptName signatureToValidate

Answer (score 0):

In my case the password was incorrect of the API call was incorrect.

You should go to [Apple Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login) > Users and Access > Shared Secret :

Then `Create` (or copy if you already have one) the shared secret.

Then in the API call you should include this code in the `password` field of the body:

```
exports.postDataApple = async (receiptData) => {
    const res = await fetch(process.env.APPLE_VERIFY_RECEIPT_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
             "Content-type": "application/json",
             "Accept": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "password": process.env.APPLE_SECRET_STRING,
            "receipt-data": receiptData,
        }),
    });
    return res !== undefined && res.status !== undefined && res.status === 200
        ? await res.json()
        : undefined;
}
```